# Map db-functionresult to jpa entity property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have here a table, where the date is a number. (days since year 0)
In the database (oracle) there is a custom function, which converts the number to a date.

Is there an easy way to use that in an jpa Entity?

I just need this for reading. 
Sure, I could read out the number and convert it myself, but it would be better if i just could use the function.

Something like:

```
@Entity
public class Person{

@Column(name="toCustomDate(dateAsNumber)")
private Date date;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best shot would be to look into the @Formula annotation, or simply save that date instead of the number in your database?

Comment: The table is about 15 years old and still in use in many different applications. But the @Formula annotation does it for me!